# Merged C with another drive, Windows 7 not booting

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I am running Windows 7 and my C drive had very little space left on it. I used Easus Partition Manager to extend my E drive. I of course took a backup of my E Drive. However, after performing the operations and attempting to reboot the computer, it would open onto a black screen with the mouse pointer on it. I waited for 5 minutes and no change, I could only assume it had hung. I can boot it in safe mode with no issue. How do I boot normally?

Comment: tried repairing using the f8 tools - first option during boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repair booting windows, follow these steps

1. Boot From the Windows Install Disc
2. And then click through until you see the “Repair your computer” link
   in the lower left-hand corner
3. You’ll need to choose the correct installation of Windows and then
   click the Next button
4. And then you’ll get to the System Recovery Options screen, where you
   can get to the Command Prompt.
5. If you want to restore the master boot record,

you can simply type in the following command:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

You can also write a new boot sector onto the system partition with this command (which is often more useful):

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

**Also you can using the Automated Startup Repair, just use the Startup Repair option from the Recovery menu .**

see [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) for screenshots ...

Comment: If they are able to boot up in start mode, then the MBR and the boot sector are already good.

Answer (score 0):

Building on MYamanT's comment, you should try bootrec /REBUILDBCD, if that doesn't work, you can use BCDEdit to look for errors in your [BCD store](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/bcd-stores.html).